# Consolidating Several Questions Marked as Duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, merging

We've got some questions that seem to cover very similar ground, specifically:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/282/what-are-the-best-podcasts

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26730/optimizing-your-daily-commute

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/road-trip-listening-material

And they have been effectively marked as duplicates of each other.  All well and good.  The thing is that I think that while the answers to all the questions have largely worked out to cover the same meta-question, the questions themselves are not really the same and don't really cover the same thing that their answers do.  I think that that is what may be preventing the merging of the answers to these 3 questions into a single question that can continue to be updated with new answers.

What I would suggest is that someone create a new question, which more broadly covers the ground in the three questions above (something like "How to pass time in the car") and then we merge all the answers from the 3 questions above into that single question, which can then be left open for future additions.

Does that make sense to anyone else?

Comment: Merge, then edit the question.

Comment: I can't see much real duplication with these examples. They are just similar topics.

Comment: Then should they have been marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

That strikes me as three very different ways of answering three very different questions that *happen* to share the same answer.

Sharing an answer doesn't mean they're the same question.

One of the primary interfaces to this site is through Google, where people often search by typing questions. If you merge these three different questions, you're reducing the chances that someone who has one of the three questions can actually find their answer.

Comment: The downside, at least in my opinion, is that you're spreading very similar answers out over different questions; in this specific example, a really great answer featuring a killer-awesome podcast might be in question 2, but is missed by viewers of questions 1 and 3, unless they are dissatisfied enough with the answers on question 1 / question 3 to actually go looking at the links to question 2.

Comment: Maybe keep all 3 questions for SEO purposes, but merge all the answers underneath one of them, so that there's a single definitive 'list' of answers?  If they're not the same question, should they have been marked duplicate?